# Could a lamprey attack a swimmer in coastal waters around the UK?

Tags: uk, swimming

I have seen two articles about bloodsucking lampreys in UK rivers, which warn swimmers about the risks of lamprey attacks when swimming in rivers and lakes. Our river lamprey spend their adult lives in the sea and only return to the rivers to breed. Is it possible to be attacked by a lamprey when swimming in the sea?

https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2016/may/15/specieswatch-lamprey-ancient-fish-vertebrate-spawn-british-rivers

https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/672972/Blood-sucking-vampire-fish-on-rise-UK-waters

Comment: if its in a tabloid news paper you can safely assume its BS.

Comment: @Idgorman, The Guardian is not exactly a tabloid news paper...

Comment: @fgysin in the UK the Guardian is a bit hit and miss for 'trusted' sources. The Express though, they enjoy some scaremongering. I mean the title on the site itself is clickbait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no certainty on this answer as there are a few species of lamprey, only one of which spends all its life in fresh water. The sea lamprey is probably the most likely to attach to a swimmer - so the answer would be yes. However, the risk is relatively small as sea lamprey are not commonly found in British waters as a general population - it seems mostly Northern areas such as [Norway, North Sea and the Baltic](https://britishseafishing.co.uk/sea-lamprey/).

The same source above has this to say about human attacks:

> Lampreys do not attack humans as they are adapted to attach themselves
> to cold-  blooded fish and not warm-blooded mammals. Occasionally
> lamprey will attempt  to attach themselves to a swimmer but they can
> be fairly easily removed, and  would probably detach themselves anyway
> when the realise that they are not  feeding on a fish. Swimmers in
> America’s Great Lakes appear to be the most  commonly ‘attacked’ by
> lampreys. The famous Canadian long distance swimmer  Marilyn Bell
> successfully swam the thirty-two mile width of Lake Ontario in  1954
> when she was just sixteen years old. Along with strong winds, high
> waves  and bad weather she listed attacks from lamprey which
> constantly attached  themselves to her swimming suit and attempted to
> feed on her as one of the  biggest challenges of the swim.

However, I can not find any record of statistics on lamprey attacks other than mention that they are very rare - so probably not a thing to be concerned about in either fresh or salt water.